# Where can I find good free quality VFX effects stock library?

Tags: visual-effects

I'm having fun with HitFilm software and playing with my kids to make movies. I'd like to add some VFX to our creations. Where can I find a good bunch of stock video and audio effects?

Usually our movies are Full HD resolution.

Answer (score 2):

I've just found this nice [Video & Filmmaker Magazine](http://videoandfilmmaker.com/wp/index.php/free-stuff/) list of free stuff.
Some of them:

- [Chroma Key Backgrounds](https://www.youtube.com/user/acterencom/videos)
- [Cute Stock Footage](http://www.cutestockfootage.com/)
- [LightLeakLove](http://lightleaklove.com/products/light-free)

Answer (score 2):

https://www.actionvfx.com/collections/free-vfx/category

https://www.productioncrate.com/

These are the best free ressources I found, especially the ones from ActionVFX

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for free VFX you might want to check out

https://nomadnationstore.com/

They offer a monthly growing library for free VFX Assets in HD and 4K

No registration or whatever needed. Just download and have fun.